# Django doesn't match pattern as expected and appends slash w/ redirect

Tags: django, apache, redirect, django-views

I have an issue where my Django site is not matching the pattern in my urls.py:

```
url(r'label/(?P<name_value>.*)$', 'name.views.label', name='label'),
```

When I request the url at

```
http://<site>/name/label/foo
```

...instead of going to the view 'label', it 302 Redirects with a appended trailing slash.

NOTE: This only works when I move the site to our test environment. When I do this with Django's built in mini-server (manage.py runserver), it doesn't append a slash and goes right to the 'label' view exactly as I intend.

In the test environment, we are using Django 1.3 and Apache 2.2.8

Here's the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ******************
    ServerAdmin ******************
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

    Alias /media /home/media
    <Location /media>
        SetHandler None
    </Location>

    <Directory /home/media>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    PythonDebug On
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE site.settings
    PythonPath "['/home/code', '/home/code/site'] + sys.path"
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure Apache is not doing the redirect for you? Verify that Django is receiving the request!

Comment: Django is receiving the request. I found that if I comment out flatpages in settings.py, it functions as intended.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash), you should put the following in your Django settings file:

```
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

Comment: So, just to clarify: I want APPEND_SLASH to be true. The problem is not that the slash is being appended. The problem is that on my test server, the pattern is not matching to the urls.py

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
url(r'label/(?P<name_value>[\w_-]+)$', 'name.views.label', name='label'),
```

Comment: Didn't work - still getting redirected, though I agree narrowing the regex a bit from "everything" is a good idea. also, I believe you have an extra right parens in there